# How can I implement Android Background Service in NativeScript targeting both API Level 26+ and below

Tags: android, nativescript, background-service

I need to implement a Background Service in NativeScript which will get user location each x minutes, make a request to my API, and depending on the response, emit a local notification.

So I started searching for ways to implement this, which led me to this NativeScript [repository](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services). As stated in the README:

> The current implementation utilizes the NotificationChannel, which was added in API Level 26. If you want to target lower API Levels, take a look at the older implementation [Alarm Manager Implementation](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services/tree/implementation-prior-apiLevel21). Have in mind, that this approaches is not supported with API Level 26 or newer due to limitations in the OS.

I need to support Android 5.1+ (API Level 22+), so the new implementation will not work for me, instead, I should use the older Alarm Manager Implementation as mentioned. The problem is, as you can see in the quote, this approach is not supported with API Level 26+.

And as everyone knows, Google is forcing new apps to target at least API Level 28. So, how can I implement a Background Service which will work from API Level 22 to 28?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to the example in the [nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/background-service.ts) plugin repo, works for all supported versions of Android.

```
     if (device.sdkVersion < "26") {
        @JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService")
        class BackgroundService extends (<any>android).app.Service {
            constructor() {
                super();
                return global.__native(this);
            }
            onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId) {
                console.log('service onStartCommand');
                this.super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
                return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
            }
            onCreate() {
                console.log('service onCreate');
                _startWatch();
            }
            onBind(intent) {
                console.log('service onBind');
            }
            onUnbind(intent) {
                console.log('service onUnbind');
            }
            onDestroy() {
                console.log('service onDestroy');
                _clearWatch();
            }
        }
        return BackgroundService;
    } else {
        @JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26")
        class BackgroundService26 extends (<any>android.app).job.JobService {
            constructor() {
                super();
                return global.__native(this);
            }
            onStartJob(): boolean {
                console.log('service onStartJob');
                _startWatch();
                return true;
            }
            onStopJob(jobParameters: any): boolean {
                console.log('service onStopJob');
                this.jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
                _clearWatch();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return BackgroundService26;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, how didn’t I see this? Guess it’s not specified in the README. Anyway, gonna try this later and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript, so when I try to build it gives me an error on the annotations.

Comment: Refer the {N} Android marshalling docs for JavaScript equivalent of annotations.

Comment: Ok, I solved this by installing and enabling a Babel plugin, now there's another problem:
Error: com.tns.system.classes.loading.LookedUpClassNotFound: Class "com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService" not found.
I also tried to change it to my app package, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Look at the full example code, an entry of the file path should be added to Webpack config.

Comment: Add `<service
   android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
   android:enabled="true"
 />` and `<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService" />` to your AndroidManifesl so that Android registers these classes as services. Also, you need to tell Webpack to wrap the service class (Manoj's code). In webpack.config.js, in `appComponents` array ( after "Add your custom Activities, Services") add this line `resolve(__dirname, "./src/app/path-to-your-js-class-file.js")`

Comment: Did everything you mentioned @MickMorely and still it throws a LookedUpClassNotFound exception

Comment: @Deeh Try a clean build, the only reason for class not found exception could be that your class is not included on build.

Comment: @Manoj deleted node_modules and platforms, uninstalled the app from the device (emulator), installed the dependencies again with tns install, tried to run with tns run android --clean and still the same error. Worth mentioning that I changed the namespace of the 2 background service classes, both in background-service.js (in the Proxy annotations) and in android-manifest.xml. I'm also not using TypeScript, so to make the Proxy annotations work I did install @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators and enabled it in babel-config.js with legacy: true.

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve this problem by replacing the Proxy annotation by NativeScript extend method, just like in this doc: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages#full-fledged-example The only problem now is that nothing is happening, no console.logs of the service is printed.

Comment: I haven't personally used babel with {N}, but your description sounds like the TypeScript compilation didn't work.

Comment: Now, when I try to start the background service from my component (see https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.ts) I get the following error:
[Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Also, if I replace BackgroundServiceClass.class with just BackgroundServiceClass, now this error happens: [Error: Cannot marshal JavaScript argument function getBackgroundServiceClass() { @Manoj

Comment: @Deeh, back to the `LookedUpClassNotFound` exception before replacing Proxy. I had the same ghost issue several months ago, which I dealt with for so long. After so many investigating hours I found that it was due to updating tns-android from 5.3.0 to 5.4.0. After going back to tns-android version 5.3.0 - everything worked just great as it was before. Hope this helps. I'm not sure if I also had to downgrade nativescript-angular to v7.1.0.

Comment: Well, I could make it work, thank's guys. The NullPointerException that I mentioned earlier was because I made a typo in the background-service.js file. When I was exporting the main method, I was not calling it "()", just passing the method name, so the method was not being called and not returning the correct class. Now everything's working. I'm just having a problem with nativescript-local-notifications, but I'm gonna open a new question for it.

Comment: I'm having a problem with nativescript-local-notifications plugin as well. It keeps crashing all the time on Android. Make sure to use plugin version 3.2.2 and below with nativescript < 6.0. Plugin version 4.0.0+ with nativescript 6+.

Comment: How can we make the job service `STICKY`? My service stops when app is closed. How to fix that?